# Realizar un programa que de acuerdo al numero mayor y menor de la matiz lo debe se sustituir con un asterisco en java

Tags: java

en la universidad me piden un programa en donde los números menor y mayor dentro de una matriz deben ser sustituidos por un asterisco. Los valores dentro de la matriz se ingresan mediante el teclado, primero se muestra la matriz original y después la matriz con los asteriscos en las posiciones de los valores menor y mayor. Ya tengo el código para saber cuál es el valor menor y mayor, lo que se me dificulta es sustituir esos valores por un asterisco, por ejemplo, recorrí la matriz usandos dos for y pues el número menor fue almacenado en una variable asi como el número mayor, volvi a recorrer la matriz en una línea nueva usando dos for y se me ocurrió usar un if en donde si la matriz en la posición [x][y]==numeroMenor se debe sustituir por un asterisco, es decir, si la condición se cumple la matriz en la posición [x][y]='*'; pero esto no resultó ya que el esterisco es un caracter y la matriz es int. Necesito ayuda. A continuación se muestra mi avance.

```
    Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
    int f, c;
    System.out.print ("Ingresa el número de filas: ");
    f=a.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Ingresa el número de columnas: ");
    c=a.nextInt();
    int mat [][] = new int [f][c];
    int matcopia [][] = new int [f][c];
    int may=mat[0][0];
    int men=mat[0][0];
    //Para llenar la matriz.
    for (int x=0; x<mat.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<mat.length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print ("Ingresa el valor en la posición ["+x+"]["+y+"]: ");
            mat[x][y]=a.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.print ("MATRIZ ORIGINAL");
    System.out.println();
    //Para mostrar la matriz original.
    for (int x=0; x<mat.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<mat.length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print (" "+mat[x][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
        
    //Para saber que número es el mayor y menor..
    for (int x=0; x<mat.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<mat.length; y++)
        {
            if (mat[x][y]>may)
            {
                may=mat[x][y];
            }
            if (mat[x][y]<men)
            {
                men=mat[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
        
    for (int x=0; x<mat.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<mat.length; y++)
        {
            if (mat[x][y]==may || mat[x][y]==men)
            {
                mat[x][y]='*';
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    System.out.print ("MATRIZ FINAL");
    System.out.println();
    for (int x=0; x<mat.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<mat.length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print (" "+mat[x][y]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print ("El número mayor es: "+ may);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print ("El número menor es: "+ men);    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos, como estudiante de programación está es la solución que encontré:**

Cambié los valores a String, para poder sustituir el número por "*". Aunque quizás otra forma sería cambiar la matriz de int a String.

Uno de los problemas era que las variables mayor y menor las inicializabas antes de dar un valor a la matriz "mat". Por lo tanto siempre aparecía un 0.

Aquí dejo tu código con una posible solución. Hice comentarios explicativos. Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /** cambie las variables a Strings, así como los métodos que recoge por teclado por nextLine() (Strings)*/
    
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String f;
    String c;
    System.out.print("Ingresa el número de filas: ");
    f = a.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ingresa el número de columnas: ");
    c = a.nextLine();
    String[][] mat = new String[Integer.parseInt(f)][Integer.parseInt(c)];

    // Para llenar la matriz.
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mat.length; y++) {
            System.out.print("Ingresa el valor en la posición [" + x + "][" + y + "]: ");
            mat[x][y] = a.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /* Inicializo menor y mayor después de proporcionarle un valor a la matriz */
    String may = mat[0][0];
    String men = mat[0][0];

    // Para mostrar la matriz original.
    System.out.println("MATRIZ ORIGINAL");
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mat.length; y++) {
            System.out.print(" " + mat[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Para saber que número es el mayor y menor..
    /**
     * Creo una variable que compruebe a cada vuelta del bucle si el numero en curso
     * es mayor o menor al número actual recorrido por el bucle de la matriz.Si se
     * cumple la condición se asigna mayor o menor al "numero en curso".
     */
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mat[x].length; y++) {
            String numeroEnCurso = mat[x][y];
            System.out.println(numeroEnCurso + "numero en curso");
            if (Integer.parseInt(numeroEnCurso) > Integer.parseInt(may)) {
                may = numeroEnCurso;
            }

            if (Integer.parseInt(numeroEnCurso) < Integer.parseInt(men)) {
                men = numeroEnCurso;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Recorro de nuevo la matriz, ahora compruebo si durante el recorrido de la matriz:
     * el número a recorrer es igual a mayor entonces sustituye por un "asterisco".
     */
    
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mat[x].length; y++) {

            if (mat[x][y] == may) {
                mat[x][y] = "*";
            }
            if (mat[x][y] == men) {
                mat[x][y] = "*";
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("MATRIZ FINAL");
    System.out.println();
    for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mat.length; y++) {
            System.out.print(" " + mat[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("El número mayor es: " + may);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("El número menor es: " + men);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La matriz es de tipo *int* por lo cual no puedes incluir un asterisco, si lo que necesitas es solo mostrarlo por consola lo mejor es solo mostrar el asterisco cuando sean el valor menor o mayor, algo como esto

```
        System.out.print ("MATRIZ FINAL");
        System.out.println();
        for (int x = 0; x < mat.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mat.length; y++) {
                
                //Si el valor actual es igual al menor o mayor que ya has guardado 
                //muestra el asterisco
                if (mat[x][y] == may || mat[x][y] == men){
                    System.out.print (" * ");
                } else {
                //Si no haz lo que ya tenías echo
                    System.out.print (" " + mat[x][y] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print ("El número mayor es: "+ may);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print ("El número menor es: "+ men);
```

Si te pidieran que dentro de la matriz tiene que estar el asterisco tendrías que hacer la matriz String y guardar los números como String, un saludo y espero que te ayude.